# Single pie chart input from two excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a single pie chart which takes input from two different excel sheets. For example: My excel document has 3 sheets( sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3). I want to make a single pie chart in sheet 3,which takes input from sheet 1 & sheet 2 with a options to select the input from either sheet 1 or sheet 2 in the sheet 3.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to construct a helper table that pulls the data from the other sheets, especially if the pie needs to include data from more than one sheets, because pie charts cannot plot data from different sheets.

If the data for the pie is all on one sheet, you could create a dynamic range name that changes the range based on the user selection, then use that range name as the pie series source.